# Can this be done without integration by substitution?

Tags: integration

Assuming that g is a continous function in the interval $[a,b]$ and $c$ is a non-zero constant, I have to show that:

$\int^b_ag(x)dx=\int^{b+c}_{a+c}g(x-c)dx$

Now my question is whether this is possible without using integration by substitution, i.e. is it acceptable to do the following?

$G(b)-G(a)=[G(x-c)]^{b+c}_{a+c}$

$G(b)-G(a)=G(b+c-c)-G(a+c-c)$

$G(b)-G(a)=G(b)-G(a)$

Hope someone can explain.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your proof, but I don't think it's really any different from using substitution

Comment: Shouldn't you start from either the LHS or RHS and then arrive at the other side? The proof starts by assuming that the two sides are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is O.K. You have used that $G(x-c)$ is an anti-derivative of $g(x-c)$.

Such an argument I will call "the simplest form of substitution."

Answer (score 2):

Your working is correct.

Alternatively, when $x$ is shifted by $c$ units to one side, the integrand function's argument must be shifted $c$ units on the opposite side. Refer to the graph:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

Note: If $$a\le x\le b \Rightarrow a+c\le x+c\le b+c,$$ 
then 
$$g(a)\le g(x)\le g(b)\Rightarrow g(a-c)\le g(x-c)\le g(b-c).$$

Comment: Very helpful. It makes me wonder what happens if you scale instead. For example:

$\int^b_ag(x)dx=\int^{cb}_{ca}g(x/c)dx$

$\Rightarrow$

$G(b)-G(a)=[G(x/c)]^{cb}_{ca}$

$\Leftrightarrow$

$G(b)-G(a)=G(b)-G(a)$;

But if I use integration by substitution by setting $u=x/c\Rightarrow$$du/dx=1/c$$\Leftrightarrow$$dx=cdu$ then the RHS becomes:

$\int^{cb}_{ca}g(x/c)dx=c\int^b_ag(u)du$$=$$c[G(b)-G(a)]$;

Hope someone can help me explaining what is going on here.

Sorry for the text format, I don't know how to break lines in a comment.